# Missing Module when using DryValidations to validate query params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry-rb

I have a jsonapi endpoint where I get the query parameter "include" with several objects seperated by a ","
Now, I validate my params with Dry::Validations and would like to preproccess this field so that I get an array of strings. 
To achive this I made this according to the docu:

```
module CustomTypes
  include Dry::Types.module

  IncludeRelatedObject = Types::String.constructor do |itm|
    itm.split(',')&.map :chomp
  end
end
```

Now, when I run my tests I get this error:

> Failure/Error:
>     IncludeRelatedObject = Types::String.constructor do |itm|
>       itm.split(',')&.map :chomp
>     end
>
> NameError:
>     uninitialized constant CustomTypes::Types

And this is my validation:

```
Dry::Validation.Params do
  configure do
    config.type_specs = true
  end
  optional(:include, CustomTypes::IncludeRelatedObject).each { :filled? & :str? }
end
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include Dry::Types.module` basically inflects constants into the module it’s being included into. You got `CustomTypes::String` amongst others and this is what should be referenced in your custom type:

```
module CustomTypes
  include Dry::Types.module

  # IncludeRelatedObject = Types::String.constructor do |itm|
  IncludeRelatedObject = CustomTypes::String.constructor do |itm|
    itm.split(',').map(&:chomp)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

To define a custom type for validations you should use a Types module. So you should change the module name from `CustomTypes` to `Types`.

```
module Types
  include Dry::Types.module

  IncludeRelatedObject = Types::String.constructor do |itm|
    itm.split(',')&.map :chomp
  end
end
```